# Catching exceptions from Guzzle

Tags: php, api, functional-testing, guzzle

I'm trying to catch exceptions from a set of tests I'm running on an API I'm developing and I'm using Guzzle to consume the API methods. I've got the tests wrapped in a try/catch block but it is still throwing unhandled exception errors. Adding an event listener as described in their docs doesn't seem to do anything. I need to be able to retrieve the responses that have HTTP codes of 500, 401, 400, in fact anything that isn't 200 as the system will set the most appropriate code based on the result of the call if it didn't work.

Current code example

```
foreach($tests as $test){

        $client = new Client($api_url);
        $client->getEventDispatcher()->addListener('request.error', function(Event $event) {        

            if ($event['response']->getStatusCode() == 401) {
                $newResponse = new Response($event['response']->getStatusCode());
                $event['response'] = $newResponse;
                $event->stopPropagation();
            }            
        });

        try {

            $client->setDefaultOption('query', $query_string);
            $request = $client->get($api_version . $test['method'], array(), isset($test['query'])?$test['query']:array());


          // Do something with Guzzle.
            $response = $request->send();   
            displayTest($request, $response);
        }
        catch (Guzzle\Http\Exception\ClientErrorResponseException $e) {

            $req = $e->getRequest();
            $resp =$e->getResponse();
            displayTest($req,$resp);
        }
        catch (Guzzle\Http\Exception\ServerErrorResponseException $e) {

            $req = $e->getRequest();
            $resp =$e->getResponse();
            displayTest($req,$resp);
        }
        catch (Guzzle\Http\Exception\BadResponseException $e) {

            $req = $e->getRequest();
            $resp =$e->getResponse();
            displayTest($req,$resp);
        }
        catch( Exception $e){
            echo "AGH!";
        }

        unset($client);
        $client=null;

    }
```

Even with the specific catch block for the thrown exception type I am still getting back

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Guzzle\Http\Exception\ClientErrorResponseException' with message 'Client error response [status code] 401 [reason phrase] Unauthorized [url]
```

and all execution on the page stops, as you'd expect. The addition of the BadResponseException catch allowed me to catch 404s correctly, but this doesn't seem to work for 500 or 401 responses. Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong please.

Comment: Is this code under a namespace? If so, unless you're `use`ing the exceptions, you may need to prefix them with `\` to explicitly state the FQ Class. So, for example, '\Guzzle\Http\Exception\ClientErrorResponseException'

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If the Exception is being thrown in that `try` block then at worst case scenario `Exception` should be catching anything uncaught.

Consider that the first part of the test is throwing the Exception and wrap that in the `try` block as well.

Comment: You are correct, there was a test outside of the try/catch that was throwing the exception. Silly mistake, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 171):

Depending on your project, disabling exceptions for guzzle might be necessary. Sometimes coding rules disallow exceptions for flow control. You can disable exceptions **for Guzzle 3** like this:

```
$client = new \Guzzle\Http\Client($httpBase, array(
  'request.options' => array(
     'exceptions' => false,
   )
));
```

This does not disable curl exceptions for something like timeouts, but now you can get every status code easily:

```
$request = $client->get($uri);
$response = $request->send();
$statuscode = $response->getStatusCode();
```

To check, if you got a valid code, you can use something like this:

```
if ($statuscode > 300) {
  // Do some error handling
}
```

... or better handle all expected codes:

```
if (200 === $statuscode) {
  // Do something
}
elseif (304 === $statuscode) {
  // Nothing to do
}
elseif (404 === $statuscode) {
  // Clean up DB or something like this
}
else {
  throw new MyException("Invalid response from api...");
}
```

**For Guzzle 5.3**

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['defaults' => [ 'exceptions' => false ]] );
```

Thanks to @mika

**For Guzzle 6**

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['http_errors' => false]);
```

Comment: Ever had a strange bug caused by a missing `break` ;-) But sure, it would be a good solution if you have multiple status codes you have to handle in the same way. I prefer `if`, cause switch just supports `==`.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `request.options`. Resolved my problem and saved me looking it up properly. :)

Comment: Or in Guzzle5.3: $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['defaults' => [
                                        'exceptions' => false
                                    ]]
        );

Comment: This saved my bacon on an urgent project. Thanks Trendfischer and SO!

Answer (score 49):

To catch Guzzle errors you can do something like this:

```php
try {
    $response = $client->get('/not_found.xml')->send();
} catch (Guzzle\Http\Exception\BadResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Uh oh! ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

... but, to be able to "log" or "resend" your request try something like this:

```
// Add custom error handling to any request created by this client
$client->getEventDispatcher()->addListener(
    'request.error', 
    function(Event $event) {

        //write log here ...

        if ($event['response']->getStatusCode() == 401) {

            // create new token and resend your request...
            $newRequest = $event['request']->clone();
            $newRequest->setHeader('X-Auth-Header', MyApplication::getNewAuthToken());
            $newResponse = $newRequest->send();

            // Set the response object of the request without firing more events
            $event['response'] = $newResponse;

            // You can also change the response and fire the normal chain of
            // events by calling $event['request']->setResponse($newResponse);

            // Stop other events from firing when you override 401 responses
            $event->stopPropagation();
        }

});
```

... or if you want to "stop event propagation" you can overridde event listener (with a higher priority than -255) and simply stop event propagation.

```php
$client->getEventDispatcher()->addListener('request.error', function(Event $event) {
if ($event['response']->getStatusCode() != 200) {
        // Stop other events from firing when you get stytus-code != 200
        $event->stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

thats a good idea to prevent guzzle errors like:

```
request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Guzzle\Http\Exception\ClientErrorResponseException: "Client error response
```

in your application.

Comment: This is no longer possible in Guzzle 6. Any idea how to do this with a middleware?

Answer (score 39):

In my case I was throwing `Exception` on a namespaced file, so php tried to catch `My\Namespace\Exception` therefore not catching any exceptions at all.

Worth checking if `catch (Exception $e)` is finding the right `Exception` class.

Just try `catch (\Exception $e)` (with that `\` there) and see if it works.

Comment: I wish I had scrolled down to this error the first time I had the same question. For me I was using outdated Guzzle Exception names and not catching the generic Exception because I wasn't at the root Namesapce. Adding the backslash before Exception started catching the generic Exception allowing me to see my name mismatch errors on the more specific Guzzle Exceptions. See comments on https://stackoverflow.com/a/7892917/2829359.

Comment: This was the exact issue I had too. Good answer

Comment: you are a saint

Answer (score 15):

You need to add a extra parameter with http_errors => false

```
$request = $client->get($url, ['http_errors' => false]);
```

Comment: Docs: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#http-errors

Answer (score 11):

I want to update the answer for exception handling in Psr-7 Guzzle, Guzzle7 and HTTPClient(expressive, minimal API around the Guzzle HTTP client provided by laravel).

### Guzzle7 (same works for Guzzle 6 as well)

**Using RequestException**, RequestException catches any exception that can be thrown while transferring requests.

```
try{
  $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['headers' => ['Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token]]);
  
  $guzzleResponse = $client->get('/foobar');
  // or can use
  // $guzzleResponse = $client->request('GET', '/foobar')
    if ($guzzleResponse->getStatusCode() == 200) {
         $response = json_decode($guzzleResponse->getBody(),true);
         //perform your action with $response 
    } 
}
catch(\GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException $e){
   // you can catch here 400 response errors and 500 response errors
   // You can either use logs here use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
   $error['error'] = $e->getMessage();
   $error['request'] = $e->getRequest();
   if($e->hasResponse()){
       if ($e->getResponse()->getStatusCode() == '400'){
           $error['response'] = $e->getResponse(); 
       }
   }
   Log::error('Error occurred in get request.', ['error' => $error]);
}catch(Exception $e){
   //other errors 
}
```

### Psr7 Guzzle

```
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;

try {
    $client->request('GET', '/foo');
} catch (RequestException $e) {
    $error['error'] = $e->getMessage();
    $error['request'] = Psr7\Message::toString($e->getRequest());
    if ($e->hasResponse()) {
        $error['response'] = Psr7\Message::toString($e->getResponse());
    }
    Log::error('Error occurred in get request.', ['error' => $error]);
}
```

### For HTTPClient

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
try{
    $response = Http::get('http://api.foo.com');
    if($response->successful()){
        $reply = $response->json();
    }
    if($response->failed()){
        if($response->clientError()){
            //catch all 400 exceptions
            Log::debug('client Error occurred in get request.');
            $response->throw();
        }
        if($response->serverError()){
            //catch all 500 exceptions
            Log::debug('server Error occurred in get request.');
            $response->throw();
        }
        
    }
 }catch(Exception $e){
     //catch the exception here
 }
```

Comment: `RequestException` seems to be a good way to differentiate

Answer (score 6):

Old question, but Guzzle adds the response within the exception object.  So a simple try-catch on `GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException` and then using `getResponse` on that exception to see what 400-level error and continuing from there.

Answer (score 2):

I was catching `GuzzleHttp\Exception\BadResponseException` as @dado is suggesting. But one day I got `GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException` when DNS for domain wasn't available.
So my suggestion is - catch `GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException` to be safe about DNS errors as well.

Comment: sounds like you should be catching `GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException` which is the parent of `ConnectException`, `BadResponseException` and `TooManyRedirectsException`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the latest version say 6^ and you have a JSON parameter, you can add `'http_errors' => false` to the array together with the JSON as seen below [image]

I was looking out for away to do this i.e with my JSON in there but couldn't find a straight answer.