# Guzzle 6.x and catching exceptions / PHP

Tags: php, json, rest, api, guzzle

I am PUTing to a restful blog API.  There is simple error checking in the API.  If the entry_name or entry_body is less than 8 characters, he response is as follows:

```
{
  "status":"failure",
 "message":{
        "entry_name":"The entry_name field must be at least 8 characters in length.",
        "entry_body": The entry_body field must be at least 8 characters in length." 
        }
}
```

In my web page I get this:

```
Type: GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException

Message: Client error: `PUT https://www.example.com/api/v1/Blog/blog`   
resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"status":"failure","message":
{"entry_name":"The entry_name field must be at least 8 characters in 
length.","entry_body" (truncated...)
```

I don't understand how I can catch the exception prior to guzzle spilling out the error like above.

I want to test for failure and if failure i want to display the message(s).

This is the code I have to catch exceptions:

This is my code:

```
         try {
              $response = $client->request('PUT', $theUrl);
              $theBody = $response->getBody();
        } catch (RequestException $e) {
            echo $e;
        }
```

but it sails right past the above block :-(

Comment: try-catch -> http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: Just pasted a bit of my code which I am using but it doesnt see to catch the exception.

Comment: is `use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;` present?

Comment: I see in composer only this:   "require-dev": {
            "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.0",
            "mockery/mockery": "~0.8",
            "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0"
        },
        "suggest": {
            "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "Allows for implementation of the Guzzle HTTP client"
        },

Is GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException; not in above?

Comment: let me rephrase: did you _import_ the `RequestException` class from the correct _namespace_?

Comment: that must be the problem then but that is a but beyond me.  I tried   "  use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException; but get an error as follows:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use'  (truncated)

Comment: put it after `<?php`. 

Comment: it is well inside <?php

Comment: put it _immediately_ after `<?php`. http://php.net/manual/it/language.namespaces.importing.php

Comment: Thanks.  No parse errors or other errors by the script doesn't catch the error.

Comment: Hi!  Does this help at all? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19748105/handle-guzzle-exception-and-get-http-body

I don't see that RequestException is a catchable exception in Guzzle 6.  Can you use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want Guzzle 6 to throw exceptions for 4xx and 5xx at all, you need to create a [handler stack](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/handlers-and-middleware.html) WITHOUT the http_errors middleware which is added to the stack by default:

```
$handlerStack = new \GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack(\GuzzleHttp\choose_handler());

$handlerStack->push(\GuzzleHttp\Middleware::redirect(), 'allow_redirects');
$handlerStack->push(\GuzzleHttp\Middleware::cookies(), 'cookies');
$handlerStack->push(\GuzzleHttp\Middleware::prepareBody(), 'prepare_body');

$config = ['handler' => $handlerStack]);

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client($config);
```