# How to Retrieve Form Parameters sent on a Guzzle Exception?

Tags: php, exception, guzzle6, guzzle

How to Retrieve form_params used from a Guzzle **BadResponseException** (ClientException || ServerException) Object?

I couldn't find it in the documentation.

```
try {
    $reponse = $this->client->post($uri, [
        'form_params' => $params,
        'headers' => $this->getHeaders()
    ]);
} catch (RequestException $e){
     /// get form_params here without accessing $params
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handle Guzzle exception and get HTTP body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19748105/handle-guzzle-exception-and-get-http-body)

Comment: Is `RequestException` equal to `Guzzle\Http\Exception\BadResponseException`? [Official documentation](https://guzzle3.readthedocs.io/http-client/request.html#http-errors)

Comment: the doc you posted is for guzzle 3 http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#exceptions. RequestException extends BadResponseException

Comment: What's the result of $response->getBody()->getContents() ?

Comment: The response body has the http error.

Comment: Found it on (string) $e->getRequest()->getBody()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form encoded parameters can be found on Request Body.

```
try {
    $reponse = $this->client->post($uri, [
        'form_params' => $params,
        'headers' => $this->getHeaders()
    ]);
} catch (RequestException $e){
     echo (string) $e->getRequest()->getBody();
}
```