# How To Get Relevant Error Data Message From Failed Validation And Failed Guzzle Call In Laravel

Tags: laravel, http, guzzle

I have an api call being made in `Laravel` using `Guzzle/Http`. When an error happens I catch it in a `try/catch` block. I then get the message, but the problem is, I don't want this ugly message that comes back but rather the actual nested message within the `$e` exception variable. The problem is that the getMessage() method returns a long string from `Guzzle`.

Error String from `$e->getMessage()`.

```
"""
Client error: `POST http://mywebApp.com/api/users` resulted in a `422 Unprocessable Entity` response: \n
{"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"email":["This email is not unique"]}}]\n
"""
```

All I want from this string is:

```
This email is not unique
```

The API call

```
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;

try {
    $client->request('POST', 'http://mywebApp.com/users', [
      'name' => 'John Doe',
      'email' => 'nonuniqueemail@test.com',
    ]);
} catch (RequestException $e) {
   $test = $e->getMessage();
   dd($test) //The long message from above
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handle Guzzle exception and get HTTP body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19748105/handle-guzzle-exception-and-get-http-body)

Comment: @Don'tPanic turns out I was using the wrong exception type. I needed to use `BadResponseException` instead of `RequestException` which allowed me to actually get the contents of the error with `$e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents()['errors']`

Answer (score 2):

If you look closely, the response body is actually a json and can be converted into an array containing the message and an array of errors. You can call `json_decode($data, true)` and you should get an associative array of the response. In your case something like this should work.

```
$response = $client->request('POST', 'http://mywebApp.com/users', [
    'name' => 'John Doe',
    'email' => 'nonuniqueemail@test.com',
]);
$bodyData = $response->getBody();
$errors = json_decode($bodyData, true)['errors'];
```

Comment: the `json_decode()` returns null. It might be something to do with my string not being valid json?

Comment: @Akess55 I made a mistake when first posting. I upddated the die and dump output of `$e->getMessage()`