# When making a batch geocoding request using the Geocodio API, how can I handle 422 errors?

Tags: php

I am reading in a file with some address information.  Some of the addresses are unprocessable (error code 422).  How can I return the results of the addresses that are processable and leave the error locations blank?

```
    require 'myFunctions.php';
    require_once '../../vendor/autoload.php';
    use Stanley\Geocodio\Client;

    $client = new Client('Your API key');

    //Read in address data.
    $AddressData = file('address.txt');

    //Send a request to the API.
    $location = $client->post($AddressData);
```

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zf4v5.jpg)

[Illogical character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2xAv.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* the API is automatically handling the errors and leaving them blanked, *no*? (would help if you shared a screenshot of the error) - But anyway if what you meant is to *catch* such errors (exceptions) here is the list of all possible exceptions in *Geocodio* ([source](https://github.com/Geocodio/geocodio-php)):

```
An HTTP 403 error raises a GeocodioAuthError
An HTTP 422 error raises a GeocodioDataError and the error message will be reported through the exception
An HTTP 5xx error raises a GeocodioServerError
An unmatched non-200 response will simply raise Exception
```

In your case, for a non processable address you should catch the `GeocodioDataError` exception. Buy anyway it's a good practice to catch all the supported ones ([Catch 'Em All](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gotta_Catch_'Em_All)). I guess you should be able to do something like this:

```
try
{
  $location = $client->post($AddressData);
}
catch(\Stanley\Geocodio\GeocodioAuthError)
{
  // do something
}
catch(\Stanley\Geocodio\GeocodioDataError)
{
  // do something
}
catch(\Stanley\Geocodio\GeocodioServerError)
{
  // do something
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
  // do something
}
```

---

In the attached screenshot I see you are using `Guzzle`! In `Guzzle` you can catch exceptions like this ([more read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17658283/catching-exceptions-from-guzzle)):

```
try
{
  $location = $client->post($AddressData);
}
catch (Guzzle\Http\Exception\BadResponseException $e)
{
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Added the screenshot.

Comment: Ok so now that I have the syntax for handling the error, how would I go about extracting the lat/longs for the locations that did not fail?  Apologies if this is a dumb question.  This is the very first API I have worked with.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @gente002 please have a look at [docs](https://geocod.io/docs/#batch-geocoding). The library returns a JSON that contains lat/long. Just have a look at the example response in the link above and see how you can read a JSON object in PHP. You can find the lan/long under location. e.g: `"location": {
              "lat": 38.886665,
              "lng": -77.094733
            },`

Comment: Sorry I probably didn't not ask the question very clearly.  I understand how to get the lat/long from the response as long as the request array does not cause any errors.  However, when I send a larger array that contains at least 1 address that responds as a 422 (unprocessable entity), it gives me the error that I shared.  Now, I can use your try/catch code to catch the error but now I am just back to trying to make the call to the api with that same array.  I did try a loop method, which sends each location individually but this defeats the purpose of the "bulk" request.

Comment: So, in summary, I want to send an array to the API that contains some "422 error" addresses but I still want the api to send the response with the locations that it can.  I notice the $e array in your example but I don't think that this contains what I need.

Comment: I figured out what my issue was.  In my text file there was an illogical character throwing the request off.  I understand why this was confusing to you now.  Screenshot above.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @gente002 ah that's cool that you found out the reason! Actually I have never used this API :D - glad to have helped anyway.