# Why is my Guzzle response in Laravel Command returning NULL?

Tags: php, laravel, axios, guzzle

So here's my problem : I use the EOD Financial api to get data on a stock, on a Laravel/Vue.js project.
On a Vue Component, I use axios to make a get Request like this :

```
const response1 = await axios.get("/getHistoricalDataNAME/"+String(self.stock.code)+'.'+String(self.stock.exchange)) 
                .then((response) => {
```

with the function getHistoricalDataNAME being :

```
    public function getHistoricalDataISIN(String $ISIN) {
        
        $response = Http::get('https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/eod/'.$ISIN.'?api_token='TOKEN');

        return $response->body();

    }
```

and it works perfectly. The result is an array, when I console.log() it, I have this :
[image: Console.log result]

Now, I'm trying to the exact same thing in a Laravel Command. So I made this command :

```
public function handle(EODController $EODController, Client $client)
    {
        $client = new Client(['verify' => false]);

        $stock = Stock::find(8);

        $stockEODname = strval($stock->code).'.'.strval($stock->exchange);

        $EOD = $client->get('https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/eod/'.$stockEODname.'?api_token=TOKEN');

        var_dump(json_decode($EOD->getBody()->getContents()));
    }
```

and it doesnt work. The var_dump just return NULL. The name of the stock is good, the $EOD variable is valid, everything seems fine but I don't know how to get an array like with the Axios method. What am I doing wrong ? Thank you !

Comment: I would suggest debugging the code in your laravel command. $url = https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/eod/'.$stockEODname.'?api_token=TOKEN' and var_dump($url) that before passing it to the client for the request

Comment: use try catch and catch the RquestException from guzzle error and log it to database, then you can know the exact error, take [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64603614/9471283) as reference

Comment: i would suggest you to check for the headers that you're sending in the axios request, and copy those in the guzzle request... usually is this the problem