# Paypal SDK Payouts - cannot catch Exception and Receive http 400

Tags: php, paypal, sdk

Hi I currently try to implement the following : someone is paying for something via paypal - a third person should receive like 50% of the price on their paypal account afterwards. So I always want to folow the steps : Person A pays 10€, I receive 10 €, I pay 5€ to Person C.

The first part is working via paypal sdk in php, the second part (transfering money to another person is not working well currently...)

This is my code for this

```
 $payouts = new \PayPal\Api\Payout();

 $senderBatchHeader = new \PayPal\Api\PayoutSenderBatchHeader();

 $senderBatchHeader->setSenderBatchId(uniqid())
     ->setEmailSubject("Test.");

 $senderItem1 = new \PayPal\Api\PayoutItem();

 $senderItem1->setRecipientType('Email')
            ->setNote('Test.')
            ->setReceiver('test@paypalsandbox.de')
            ->setSenderItemId('test ' . uniqid())
            ->setAmount(new \PayPal\Api\Currency('{
                    "value": "5.00",
                    "currency":"EUR"
                }'));


 $payouts->setSenderBatchHeader($senderBatchHeader)
   ->addItem($senderItem1);

 // For Sample Purposes Only.
 $request = clone $payouts;

// ### Create Payout
try {
    $output = $payouts->createSynchronous($this->_api_context);
} catch (PayPapl\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
            //todo add exception handler
    dd('test');

    ResultPrinter::printError("Created Batch Payout", "Payout", null, $request, $ex);
    exit(1);
}

dd('test');
```

I cannot catch the error somehow. It says

PayPalConnectionException in PayPalHttpConnection.php line 174:
Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payouts?sync_mode=true.

I'm implementing this using laravel 5.1

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your business model, REST API is not a good option to use.
Paypal has the adaptive payment API which enables you to send money in many different scenarios, from simple to complex.So in your case, you may refer the [chained payment](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/), the sender pays the primary receiver an amount, from which the primary receiver pays secondary receivers. The sender only knows about the primary receiver, not the secondary receivers. The secondary receivers only know about the primary receiver, not the sender. Adaptive payment demo [download](https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php).

Answer (score 2):

Put a '\' in front of your paypal error message. Worked for me. Its a namespace conflict.

```
try {
    $output = $payouts->createSynchronous($this->_api_context);
} catch (\PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
    //todo add exception handler
    dd('test');
    ResultPrinter::printError("Created Batch Payout", "Payout", null, $request, $ex);
    exit(1);
}catch (\Exception $e){
    dd($e->getMessage( );
}
```

[See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172715/try-catch-block-in-php-not-catching-exception)