# PHPUnit try catch does not work in a test case

Tags: php, exception, phpunit

I tried to catch an exception inside a PHPUnit test but it does not work as I expected. The exception seems to be caught in a higher level and I do not understand why.

```
public function testException()
    {
        echo 'Enter';
        try {
            throw new Exception('error.');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'catch Exception';
        }
        echo 'End';
    }
```

In the output only 'Enter' is visible. I do not reach the 'End'.
(I am using PHP7)

Thanks

Edit:
Replacing all `Exception` with `\Exception` solved my issue

Comment: try replacing all `Exception`  with `\Exception`

Comment: You should also list your `import` statements, just to see what exceptions you are actually using in your test.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Try/Catch block in PHP not catching Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172715/try-catch-block-in-php-not-catching-exception)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Handling exceptions can be tricky, especially when they are called `Exception` :-)

Just look at all the feedback [this (almost the same) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172715/try-catch-block-in-php-not-catching-exception) has generated.

Now, the exception is not caught only if does not match to the expected class. In this case it is definitely because of non-precise `Exception` class names specification, which will most certainly be fixed by specifying them as `\Exception`.

As smartly put by a commenter from the mentioned question thread:

> Without the backslash Exception is specific to the namespace and won't be matched (or caught).