# Php Exceptions are not catched

Tags: php

I'm trying to make an error handler to convert errors to JSON for my ajax requests.
I've got a DB class which handles all MySql queries and which calls the following function when errors happens:

```
private function halt($msg)
{
    $this->Error = @mysqli_error($this->Link_ID);
    $this->Errno = @mysqli_errno($this->Link_ID);

    if ($this->throw = true) {
        throw new \Exception("Mysql Error: $msg. Error: $this->Errno ($this->Error)");
    } else if ($this->Halt_On_Error == "no") {
        return;
    }

    $this->haltmsg($msg);

    if ($this->Halt_On_Error != "report") {
        die("Session halted.");
    }
}
```

In my ajax script, I've got some functions like this one:

```
private function add()
{
    $this->changeErrorCatcher(ON);
    try {
        $obj = $this->mgr->getEmptyObject();
        foreach ($this->fields as $field) {
            if (!$this->form->vide($field) && $field != "id") {
                $name = "set" . ucfirst($field);
                $obj->$name($this->form->get($field));
            }
        }
        $this->mgr->create($obj);
        Ajax::Response(AJX_ACC, "Ok", $obj->getId());
    } catch (\Throwable $e) {
        Ajax::Response(AJX_ERR, $e->getMessage(), $e);
    }
}
```

changeErrorCatcher function:

```
private function changeErrorCatcher(bool $onOff)
{
    if ($onOff) {
        set_error_handler(function ($errno, $errstr) {
            throw new \Exception($errstr, $errno);
        }, E_ALL | E_ERROR | E_STRICT | E_USER_ERROR);
    } else {
        restore_error_handler();
    }
}
```

My problem is that the try/catch block in the add() function is not working: the line "$this->mgr->create($obj);" calls my DB class, so the halt() function is called when an error occurs and an Exception is thrown, but the catch block is never launched, and the text of the Exception is sent as ajax result (Making my JS fail parsing JSON)

I already tried solutions proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172715/try-catch-block-in-php-not-catching-exception) but nothing works (\Exceptions instead of Exception (even \Throwable does not work), disabling XDEBUG, changing error handler)

EDIT: I tried changing this in halt function:

```
if ($this->throw = true) {
    throw new \Exception("Mysql Error: $msg. Error: $this->Errno ($this->Error)");
}
```

Into:

```
if ($this->throw = true) {
        try {
            throw new \Exception("Mysql Error: $msg. Error: $this->Errno ($this->Error)");
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new \Exception("Mysql Error: $msg. Error: $this->Errno ($this->Error)  ".$e->getTraceAsString());
        }
    }
```

Now I've got the stack trace in my ajax result, so the first exception is well catched but not the second...
The stack trace shows me it is the line "$this->mgr->create($obj);" which throws exception.

Comment: Got a stack trace? It's likely the exception is being thrown prior to hitting your try/catch block.

Comment: Exemple ajax result:
Mysql Error: Invalid SQL: INSERT INTO pays (pa_libelle, pa_code_2, pa_continent) VALUES ('GuinÃ©e', '', 'Afrique'). Error: 1062 (Duplicate entry '' for key 'index_pa_code_2')

This error can only be thrown from the "$this->mgr->create($obj);" line, cause it's the only line calling my DB class

Answer (score 0):

Your code is failing because mysqli is returning an error instead of an exception. Set the following in your connection constructor prior to running any queries to tell it to throw exceptions instead of errors and your code should work:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

As your query is returning a duplicate id error, you might also consider updating the SQL statement to use `INSERT IGNORE` or `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` instead to handle the error at the data layer level.

Comment: It does not change anything. See edit for precisions

Comment: The error you are receiving is a high enough priority to kill execution and cannot be supressed. You will need to handle the error appropriately instead of attempting to silence it.

Comment: Use `INSERT IGNORE` and then check for the count of rows changed (which will equal the number of rows provided unless a duplicate key exists).

Comment: I'm not trying to silence it but to send it as JSON object in response, in order to tell the user where is the problem, it is a manual throw() so I can't understand why it has high priority

Comment: Because mysqli mostly. If you use PDO you can cast errors as exceptions more easily.

Comment: And the problem is not just for this request, I need this to work with any MySQL error, not just INSERT errors

Comment: The priority is not your exception. Mysqli is throwing a fatal error before your code is even reached. You need to put the above mysqli directive in **before any queries are run at all** for it to work.

Comment: Eg in your bootstrap file, or where your initial database credentials are declared.

Comment: See my edit: My code is necessarily reached as the try/catch block in the DB class is called and the stack trace returned. If I change anything in the message of the Exception I throw, the returned message is changed to

Comment: You have a single `=` instead of `==` in your conditional, so it’s evaluating whether the condition is set to true instead of whether it is true (which will always evaluate true).

Comment: Oh yes, didn't saw this, thx. Anyway, that's not the problem, the exceptions are still not catched

Comment: You need to fix the index issue. There is not a way to automate away sloppy database schema (or faulty insert statements) blocking your inserts. You will need to use `INSERT IGNORE` or `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, whichever is more appropriate.